# Change defaultCloseOperation() in Netbeans?

Tags: java, operation

I need to set to open a different JFrame as the defaultCloseOperation of the JFrame that I'm currently working.

Can I do that in Netbeans ?

Comment: Add a `WindowListener` to the first frame that makes the second frame and use `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: sidenote - Netbeans is just an IDE. your question is about java programming language and not restricted to IDE scope.

Comment: yeah, I'll remove that tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html

Add a `WindowListener` to the first frame and when it closes, make the seconds frame and close this first frame. Then set `defaultCloseOperation` to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.

Non-working code just so you get the idea:

```
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener {
    (other stuff)
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        //make second frame
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I added implements WindowListener part to code and set defaultCloseOperation to DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE but it didn't work the new NewFrame().setVisible(true) inside windowClosed method

Comment: @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        //make second frame
        dispose();
        new NewFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: @HarinLakmal so the new frame just doesn't appear?

Comment: @HarinLakmal try putting a `System.out.println` in the `windowClosed`.  Does it print?

Comment: I tried that too. More click on the close button Frame remains like solid rock nothing happens.

Comment: In FirstFrame's constructor, add `addWindowListener(this);`

Comment: added implements WindowListener to NewFrame class & created addWindowListener(this); too